# Error while trying to run a SQL query with VBA excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to run a SQL query in VBA but I am getting an error:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

The query works perfectly in SQL but I am haven't managed to translate it in VBA code. The error is located at  `WS.Range("B20").CopyFromRecordset` rs line.

```vb
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection, oCmd As Object
    Dim rs As Object, SQL_1 As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet, n As Long
    
'GET DATES
    Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A&B Sankey")
        StartDate = Format(.Range("R2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
        EndDate = Format(.Range("T2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
    End With
    
'CONNECT FUNCTION
    Set oCon = DbConnect
    Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    oCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    
SQL_1 = _
" DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(20)" & vbCrLf & _
" DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(20)" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @StartDate ='" & StartDate & "'" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @EndDate ='" & EndDate & "'" & vbCrLf
SQL_1 = SQL_1 & _
" SELECT x.*, y.* INTO #temp1 FROM " & vbCrLf & _
" (SELECT [Charge_slabs_A]=count(CASE WHEN f.[FURNACE_NUMBER] =1 then f.[slab_weight] else null end)," & vbCrLf & _
"[Slab_weight_Discharged_A]=1000*avg(c.[fa_weight])," & vbCrLf & _
"[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(case when b.[Furnace]='A' then b.[charge_temperature]else null end)" & vbCrLf & _
"" & vbCrLf
    SQL_1 = SQL_1 & _
" FROM fix.dbo.Fce_HD_Hourly a " & vbCrLf & _
" LEFT JOIN ALPHADB.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims as b on DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, b.[charge_time]), 0) = a.[_TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" LEFT JOIN ALPHADB.dbo.reheats_hourly_data c ON c.[start_time]= a.[_timestamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" LEFT JOIN alphadb.dbo.HFNCPDI f on  f.[counter] = b.[mill_counter]" & vbCrLf & _
" WHERE a.[_TimeStamp] between @StartDate and @EndDate and b.[charge_time] between @StartDate and @EndDate " & vbCrLf & _
" GROUP BY a.[_TimeStamp]) as x " & vbCrLf & _
" FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Avg_DisCharg_Temp_B]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='B' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0')) else null end),[Time]= a.[_TimeStamp] " & vbCrLf & _
" FROM fix.dbo.Fce_HD_Hourly as a" & vbCrLf & _
" LEFT JOIN Mill_Temp_Aims as b on DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, b.[discharge_time]), 0) = a.[_TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" WHERE a.[_TimeStamp] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 120) AND CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate , 120) and b.[discharge_time]  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 120) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 120) " & vbCrLf & _
" GROUP BY  a.[_TimeStamp]) AS y ON y.[Time] = x.[_TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" SELECT [Charge_slabs_A],[Slab_weight_Discharged_A],[Avg_Charg_Temp_A],[Avg_DisCharg_Temp_B]" & vbCrLf & _
" FROM  #temp1 DROP TABLE #temp1"
         
'EXECUTE RESULT
    oCmd.CommandText = SQL_1
    Set rs = oCmd.Execute
    
'SHOW RESULT
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-Input Data-")
    WS.Range("B20:CC20000").ClearContents
    
    WS.Range("B20").CopyFromRecordset rs           <-------------------ERROR
    
'CLOSE
    oCon.Close
    MsgBox "Result written to " & WS.Name & _
           "For " & StartDate & "-" & EndDate, vbInformation, "Finished"
End Sub

Function DbConnect() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConn As String
    sConn = "driver={SQL server}; SERVER=; " & _
            "UID=; PWD=; DATABASE=;"
    Set DbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DbConnect.Open sConn
End Function
```

Are the connect function , execute result and the show results properly set?

Comment: See: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Parfait i have edited above. It was just a copy paste mistake. As I mention in description the query is working in SQL.

Comment: Please be sure to use latest ODBC driver such as `ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server` as `SQL Server` is an [older, non-recommended version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965100/1422451).

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your script. This will avoid `DONE IN PROC` (row counts) from being returned, which are closed recordsets with no columns in ADO.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for that I will use it in my scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially for complex queries, consider separating SQL and VBA and parameterizing the SQL as a prepared statement with qmark placeholders. ADO supports parameterization with the [ADO command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) object which coincidentally you already use! This allows you to avoid any `DECLARE` and messy, even dangerous concatenation. Also, because of parameterization, purposely use date types and avoid any `FORMAT` or `CONVERT` needs. You can also avoid `#temp1` with a single statement:

**SQL** *(save as .sql or string in an Excel cell)*

Query below uses more informative aliases and uses `AS` operator for column aliasing. Also, all system commands are consistently capitalized for readability. Please note the use of qmarks (`?`) for parameters and not @ variables. Please test query and adjust as needed.

```sql
SELECT x.[Charge_slabs_A], x.[Slab_weight_Discharged_A],
       x.[AVG_Charg_Temp_A], y.[AVG_DisCharg_Temp_B]
FROM 
   (SELECT COUNT(CASE
                    WHEN h.[FURNACE_NUMBER]=1 
                    THEN h.[slab_weight] 
                    ELSE NULL 
                 END) AS [Charge_slabs_A],
           1000 * AVG(r.[fa_weight]) AS [Slab_weight_Discharged_A],
           AVG(CASE 
                  WHEN m.[Furnace]='A' 
                  THEN m.[charge_temperature]
                  ELSE NULL 
               END) AS [AVG_Charg_Temp_A]
   FROM fix.dbo.Fce_HD_Hourly AS f
   LEFT JOIN ALPHADm.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims AS m 
        ON DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, m.[charge_time]), 0) = f.[_TimeStamp]
   LEFT JOIN ALPHADm.dbo.reheats_hourly_data AS r 
        ON r.[start_time]= f.[_timestamp]
   LEFT JOIN alphadm.dbo.HFNCPDI h
        ON  h.[counter] = m.[mill_counter]
   WHERE f.[_TimeStamp] BETWEEN ? AND ?
     AND m.[charge_time] BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY f.[_TimeStamp]
  ) AS x 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT AVG(CASE 
                 WHEN m.[FURNACE] ='B' 
                 THEN convert(real,isnull (m.[ave_disch_temp],'0')) 
                 ELSE NULL 
              END) AS [AVG_DisCharg_Temp_B],
          f.[_TimeStamp] AS [Time]
   FROM fix.dbo.Fce_HD_Hourly AS f
   LEFT JOIN Mill_Temp_Aims AS m 
        ON DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, m.[discharge_time]), 0) = f.[_TimeStamp]
   WHERE f.[_TimeStamp] BETWEEN ? AND ?
     AND m.[discharge_time] BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY f.[_TimeStamp]
  ) AS y 
ON y.[Time] = x.[_TimeStamp]
```

**VBA** *(reads in above query and binds date parameters)*

```vb
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection, oCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As Object, SQL_1 As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet, n As Long
    
'GET DATES
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A&B Sankey")
        StartDate = CDate(.Range("R2").Value)
        EndDate = CDate(.Range("T2").Value)
    End With
    
'CONNECT FUNCTION
    Set oCon = DbConnect
    Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    oCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    
'READ IN SQL
   With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       SQL_1 = .OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\my\SQL\Query.sql", 1).readall
   End With
   ' SQL_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySQLSheet").Range("A1")

'EXECUTE RESULT
   With oCmd
       .CommandText = SQL_1
                
       ' BIND ? PARAMETERS IN SQL (USING adDate TYPES)
       For n = 1 to 4
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("startdateparam" & n, adDate, adParamInput, , StartDate)
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("enddateparam" & n, adDate, adParamInput, , EndDate)
       Next n

       ' CREATE RECORDSET
       Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    
'SHOW RESULT
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-Input Data-")
        .Range("B20:CC20000").ClearContents
        .Range("B20").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

'CLOSE
    MsgBox "Result written to " & WS.Name & _
           "For " & StartDate & "-" & EndDate, vbInformation, "Finished"
    rs.Close: oCon.Close
    Set rs = Nothing: Set oCmd = Nothing: Set oCon = Nothing
End Sub

Function DbConnect() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConn As String
    sConn = "Driver={SQL Server}; SERVER=; " & _
            "UID=; PWD=; DATABASE=;"
    Set DbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DbConnect.Open sConn
End Function
```

Comment: Upped - THAT is a proper answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Parfait.  I know that you mention having separate the SQL and the VBA but theoretically speaking if I wanted to have the SQL in VBA how that would be? Is only the 'READ IN SQL affected by that change?

Comment: Yes, assign `SQL_1` to a VBA string of SQL statement. But this time without any VBA variable concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

oCmd.Execute can only execute a single SQL Command (`executes the query, SQL statement, or stored procedure specified in the CommandText` ); you are trying to execute a batch of commands: 'declare, ... set, ... select'. You can submit only one command with this method. One option is to put all this batch in a stored procedure in SQLServer and call it from VBA, or remove the declare/set parts, and replace them with ADO Command parameters.

Example query (you can easily adapt to your query):

```
Public Sub DoIt()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, _
      cmd As ADODB.Command, _
      rs As ADODB.Recordset, _
      parmStartDate As ADODB.Parameter, _
      parmEndDate As ADODB.Parameter, _
      strSql As String
  
  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  With conn
    .ConnectionString = "driver={SQL server}; SERVER=MYSSINSTANCE; UID=; PWD=; DATABASE=;"
    .Open
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "select NumDays=datediff(day, ?, ?)"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        
        Set parmStartDate = .CreateParameter("StartDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
        parmStartDate.Value = "2020-01-01"
        .Parameters.Append parmStartDate
        Set parmEndDate = .CreateParameter("EndDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
        parmEndDate.Value = "2020-03-05"
        .Parameters.Append parmEndDate
        Set rs = .Execute()
        Debug.Print rs!NumDays
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End With
    .Close
  End With
  Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the code I believe you need to open the recordset object via this:

```
rs.Open
```

As Parfait mentions in comments this should not be needed as the Execute method should open the rs (reference for alternative ways to open rs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/open-ado-connection-recordset-objects)

Also I am wondering if you need to explicitly say what sort of object rs is:

```
Dim Rs As adodb.Recordset
```

Comment: OP does a similar call with `Set rs = oCmd.Execute`.

Comment: @Parfait - apologies - yes true that should open the rs