# Django MsSQL FreeTDS - Nvarchar(max) Auto Truncates

Tags: sql-server, django, rds, freetds, nvarchar

I'm using Django that is connected to AWS' RDS MSSQL. So I'm to input very long texts, but they are generally longer than 4000 characters. In Django, this specific field is using TextField and the data type in MSSQL is nvarchar(max). So my question now is how can I configure and increase its max length. I've got the assumption that it's supposed to be infinite (of course it's not).

Help is desperately needed. I've read about it briefly here: [How to get entire VARCHAR(MAX) column with Python pypyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878291/how-to-get-entire-varcharmax-column-with-python-pypyodbc/33883901). However, I'm using RDS and I have no idea in doing this as at all.

Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: Did you try the freetds specific solution in the SO question that you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django-pyodbc-azure, upgrading from 1.11.11.0 to 1.11.13.1 fixed the issue for me.